# How do you set sigma for the Gaussian similarity kernel?

Tags: similarity, graphs, variance

Let's say we have $n$ two-dimensional vectors: $$\mathbf{x}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}_i,\dots,\mathbf{x}_n=(x_{1_1},x_{1_2})^T,\dots,(x_{i_1},x_{i_2})^T,\dots,(x_{n_1},x_{n_2})^T$$ How do you set $\sigma$ for the Gaussian similarity kernel:
$$s(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)=\exp\left(-\frac{||\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j||^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated Answer

According to a reference paper in Spectral Clustering ([von Luxburg](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10701/readings/Luxburg06_TR.pdf)) the $\sigma$ is simply set to 1. A further tuning can be applied with some visualization inspection but I did not find any discussion regarding setting this parameter.

Using code snippet below you see the effect:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def gausker(x1,x2,sigma):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(x1-x2)
    return np.exp(-dist**2/(2.*(sigma**2.)))

data = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[10,10],[10,9],[9,10],[9,9]])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1],'o',ms=20)
plt.show()
s = np.std(pdist(data))
for sigma in [1, s, 10, 100]:
    gaus = np.zeros((8,8))
    for ii in range(8):
        for jj in range(8):
            gaus[ii,jj] = gausker(data[ii,:],data[jj,:],sigma)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(gaus,extent=[0, 1, 0, 1])
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title(str(sigma))
    plt.show()
```

For Machine Learning algorithms is better to have more distinction. The Gaussian similarity kernel cares about local similarities. The image show the kernel for $\sigma=1$ [image]

Conceptually is similar to a k-nearest neighbors graph, since it considers local neighborhood and almost disregards the relationship between two nodes far apart.

[image: Data]
[image: $\sigma 1$]
[image: stddev]
[image: $\sigma 10$]
[image: $\sigma 100$]

Comment: I checked A. Ng and U.V. Luxburg papers and I kind of correct my answer. The Gaussian is not multivariate. It has just one $\sigma$ and some of them simply set it to $1$. the point is that Gaussian is not defined on the data itself but on the similarity/distance of them (i.e. $||x_i-x_j||^2$) which is simply a scalar. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's right. I've asked the question as a confirmation after reading the tutorial on spectral clustering of U.V. Luxburg. I couldn't figure out the multivariate approach to set the weights.

Comment: I wrote a simple code to show my answer. I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If your doing spectral clustering you might find the following paper of interest:

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2619-self-tuning-spectral-clustering.pdf

The authors use a sigma that locally adapts for each sample to the local environment. Useful when working with multi-scale data in my experience.